# Complex SQL Query - Time Out

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sql query:

```
WITH CTE(documents, pocname, pocphone, initialticketNo)
AS
(
   SELECT 
      SO.Documents, SO.POCName, SO.POCPhone,
      SUBSTRING(SO.Documents, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SO.Documents)) AS 'InitialCustomerTicket'
   FROM 
      ServiceOrder SO
   CROSS APPLY 
      (SELECT 
          COUNT(TECHNICIANTRIPDETAILID) TTL 
       FROM 
          TECHNICIANTRIPDETAIL 
       WHERE 
          SERVICEORDERID = SO.SERVICEORDERID 
          AND ISEQUIPMENTREPAIRED = 1) EQUIPMENT
   INNER JOIN  
      Contract CON ON CON.ContractId = SO.ContractId
   INNER JOIN 
      ClientProfile CP ON CP.ClientId = CON.ClientId
   WHERE 
      CP.ClientId = 20739 
      AND SO.CloseStatus = 1 
      AND equipment.ttl > 0 
      AND ISNULL(SO.DOCUMENTS,'') <> ''
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE initialticketNo <> ''
```

Now in above query, if you see I have calculated one field initialticketno. I want to run query again on same table serviceorder and want count of each ticket number that starts with initialticketno. When I do that as below it is taking much time, is there any way I can simplify this query?

```
WITH CTE(documents,pocname,pocphone,initialticketNo)
as
(Select SO.Documents,SO.POCName,SO.POCPhone,
SUBSTRING(SO.Documents,0,CHARINDEX('-',SO.Documents)) AS 'InitialCustomerTicket'
From ServiceOrder SO
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(TECHNICIANTRIPDETAILID) TTL FROM TECHNICIANTRIPDETAIL WHERE SERVICEORDERID = SO.SERVICEORDERID AND ISEQUIPMENTREPAIRED = 1) EQUIPMENT
Inner Join Contract CON ON CON.ContractId = SO.ContractId
Inner Join ClientProfile CP ON CP.ClientId = CON.ClientId
where CP.ClientId = 20739 AND SO.CloseStatus = 1 and equipment.ttl > 0 AND ISNULL(SO.DOCUMENTS,'') <> '')
select * from cte 
cross apply (select count(serviceorderid) ttl from serviceorder so where so.documents like cte.initialticketNo + '%') as so
where initialticketNo <> '' and so.ttl > 1
```

PS: Total records in serviceorder table is 75k.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: How long is too long, are you cancelling the execution or is it reaching a cap

Comment: It is taking 3 to 4 minutes of execution time..

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that you are missing indexes if it's that slow and your dataset is that small. I think this query would produce the same output, but I think it would be more efficient.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
      SO.Documents, SO.POCName, SO.POCPhone,
      SUBSTRING(SO.Documents, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SO.Documents)) AS 'InitialCustomerTicket'
   FROM ServiceOrder SO
   INNER JOIN Contract CON ON CON.ContractId = SO.ContractId
   INNER JOIN ClientProfile CP ON CP.ClientId = CON.ClientId
   INNER JOIN TECHNICIANTRIPDETAIL TTD ON TTD.SERVICEORDERID = SO.SERVICEORDERID 
          AND TTD.ISEQUIPMENTREPAIRED = 1
   WHERE 
      CP.ClientId = 20739 
      AND SO.CloseStatus = 1 
      AND ISNULL(SO.DOCUMENTS,'') <> ''
      and SUBSTRING(SO.Documents, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SO.Documents)) <> ''
```

Comment: Database Engine Tuning Advisor is a good way of identifying any indexes and statistics which will help lower the cost of your workload.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `Cross Apply`.  That is going to run that query for each row, so probably 75k times.  Having 2 cross applies is at least twice as bad ;)

The first query can be re-written like this

```
SELECT 
      SO.Documents, SO.POCName, SO.POCPhone,
      SUBSTRING(SO.Documents, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SO.Documents)) AS 'InitialCustomerTicket'
   FROM 
      ServiceOrder SO
   join TECHNICIANTRIPDETAIL on SERVICEORDERID = SO.SERVICEORDERID AND ISEQUIPMENTREPAIRED = 1 as 'EQUIPMENT'
   INNER JOIN  
      Contract CON ON CON.ContractId = SO.ContractId
   INNER JOIN 
      ClientProfile CP ON CP.ClientId = CON.ClientId
   WHERE 
      CP.ClientId = 20739 
      AND SO.CloseStatus = 1 
      AND ISNULL(SO.DOCUMENTS,'') <> ''
   Group by SO.Documents, SO.POCName, SO.POCPhone,
      SUBSTRING(SO.Documents, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SO.Documents)) AS 'InitialCustomerTicket'
   having count(equipment.TECHNICIANTRIPDETAILID) > 0
```

The second can be written like this:

```
 SELECT 
      SO.Documents, SO.POCName, SO.POCPhone,
      SUBSTRING(SO.Documents, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SO.Documents)) AS 'InitialCustomerTicket'
   FROM 
      ServiceOrder SO
   join TECHNICIANTRIPDETAIL on SERVICEORDERID = SO.SERVICEORDERID AND ISEQUIPMENTREPAIRED = 1 as 'EQUIPMENT'
   INNER JOIN  
      Contract CON ON CON.ContractId = SO.ContractId
   INNER JOIN 
      ClientProfile CP ON CP.ClientId = CON.ClientId
    join serviceorder as SO2 on so2.documents like so.initialticketNo + '%'
   WHERE 
      CP.ClientId = 20739 
      AND SO.CloseStatus = 1 
      AND ISNULL(SO.DOCUMENTS,'') <> ''
   Group by SO.Documents, SO.POCName, SO.POCPhone,
      SUBSTRING(SO.Documents, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SO.Documents)) AS 'InitialCustomerTicket'
   having count(equipment.TECHNICIANTRIPDETAILID) > 0
      and count(so2.serviceorderid) > 1
```

Of course, I can't run a before and after because I don't have the data, but I think that should do it.  If not it at least gives you an idea where to head - remove the `Cross Apply` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler and (likely to be) more efficient query:

```
SELECT  SO.Documents ,
        SO.POCName ,
        SO.POCPhone ,
        SUBSTRING(SO.Documents, 0, CHARINDEX('-', SO.Documents)) AS initialticketNo
FROM    ClientProfile CP
        INNER JOIN [Contract] CON ON CON.ClientId = CP.ClientId
        INNER JOIN ServiceOrder SO ON SO.ContractId = CON.ContractId
WHERE   CP.ClientId = 20739
        AND SO.CloseStatus = 1
        AND SO.Documents IS NOT NULL
        AND SO.Documents LIKE '%-%'
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   TECHNICIANTRIPDETAIL TTL
                     WHERE  TTL.ISEQUIPMENTREPAIRED = 1
                     AND TTL.SERVICEORDERID = SO.SERVICEORDERID )
```